# How to unfollow 5 users using Tweepy & Python

Tags: python, tweepy

I want to run a script that only unfollows 5 users at a time using Tweepy and Python. The following script works, but it keeps going after I unfollow 5 users. How do I get it to cut off at 5? Thanks for your help!

```
import tweepy
import time

def get_twitter_api():
    # personal details
    consumer_key = "xxxx"
    consumer_secret = "xxxx"
    access_token = "xxxx"
    access_token_secret = "xxxx"

    # authentication of consumer key and secret
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)

    # authentication of access token and secret
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)
    return api

def process():
    interval = 61
    api = get_twitter_api()

    followers = api.followers_ids(api.me().id)
    print("Followers", len(followers))
    friends = api.friends_ids(api.me().id)
    print("You follow:", len(friends))


    for friend in friends[::-1]:
        if friend not in followers:
            api.destroy_friendship(friend) 
            time.sleep(interval)
            amount = 5

if __name__ == "__main__":
    process()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a variable set to `0` before the `for` loop.
Then, you can increment the variable by `1` in your `if` statement.
And then you can add another `if` statement after that, checking to see if the variable is equal to `5`, and if so, `break` or `return`.

For example:

```
    amount = 0

    for friend in friends[::-1]:
        if friend not in followers:
            api.destroy_friendship(friend) 
            time.sleep(interval)

            amount += 1

            if amount == 5:
                break
```

You might want to `sleep` before the increment and check, if you don't want it to wait after the last one.